# handling all of the quadratic formula results

Tags: c++, math

i'm trying to display correctly all of the possible results that the quadratic formula may give, i've tried to use long double and its usefull for some cases but not for the smallest of the numbers,is there any not that complicated way to do it?

```
double a, b, c;
long double pos,neg;

cout<<"a: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"b: ";
cin>>b;
cout<<"c: ";
cin>>c;
pos = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 *a);
neg = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
cout<<"+ = "<<pos<<endl;
cout<<"- = "<<neg<<endl;
```

Comment: Can you give an example where the above is insufficient? What are sizeof(double) and sizeof(long double) on your platform?

Comment: FYI: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/). Btw. if you have doubts about the correctness of your code, please, expose sample inputs and current vs. expected outputs. (You may [edit] your question.)

Comment: Computers are not accurate in a sense which may be expected with basic math knowledge. In certain ranges, floating point values work reliable but in others not. E.g. Using `acos()` for results close to 0°, the outcome will be very inaccurate. No wonder, the function graph of cosine is nearly horizontal in this range. With a slightly modified formula, the results can be computed with `asin()` instead. Sine has a slope of roundabout 1 near 0°. Hence, it provides much more reliable results in this range.

Answer (score 2):

One problem you should deal with is: suppose the user enters 0.0 for a? Your formula will blow up. But in that case they haven't really entered a quadratic, so I think it would be fair enough to tell the user that they need to enter a non-zero value for a.

The next problem is: what if a,b,c are such that

```
b * b - 4 * a * c < 0.0
```

In that case, the quadratic has complex rather than real roots. You could either inform them that the program only deals with real roots, or adapt your program to deal with complex roots too,

Another problem is somewhat more subtle and has to do with floating point arithmetic. Suppose b is positive and that

```
b*b is much bigger than 4*a*c
```

In that case

```
sqrt( b*b-4*a*c)
```

will be relatively close to b, and when you compute

```
(-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c))
```

you will be adding two numbers of comparable size but with opposite signs. This leads to a loss of significance, that is you will end up with less accuracy than you might hope. 
The solution to this is to use the fact that

```
if x1 and x2 are the roots of a*x*x+b*x+c = 0
then x1*x2= c/a
```

So you should compute the root, x1 say, where

```
-b and sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c) have the same sign
```

via the formula, and then compute the other, x2 say, via

```
x2 = c/a/x1
```